# RPZ (response policy zone) in Windows Server 2019?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2019

BIND9 have very good function [RPZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_policy_zone).

You can create DNS zone (like malware) and add malicious domains in it.
DNS server in response is giving my defined IP address aka DNS Firewall

```
[zone file]
...
$ORIGIN com.malware.
$TTL 5  ; 5 seconds
example         A   127.0.0.1


[request]
$ dig example.com +short
127.0.0.1

[log]
(example.com): rpz QNAME Local-Data rewrite example.com/A/IN via example.com.malware
```

I wondering, if Windows Server 2019 DNS have the same native functionality?

I read all documentation regarding [DNS Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/deploy/dns-policies-overview) without any luck

Comment: Ok, I think I have to play with command

`Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name "AllowListPolicyDomain" -Action IGNORE -FQDN "NE,*.contoso.com"`

Comment: But it will results in timeout so it is no option for me :/

Comment: Only `-action deny` have fast response and return null response